# Get value from table... PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following that returns data from my table...

```
    $query = dbConnect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users a INNER JOIN actions b ON a.id = b.user_id WHERE a.id=:user_id");
    $query->bindParam(':user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $query->execute();


    if($row = $query->fetchAll()){
        $row['id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }
```

I want to print out every value in my 'check_id' column for the currently logged in user...

I've tried...

```
 if($row = $query->fetchAll()){
        $row['id'] = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $checkValue = $row['check_id'];
    }
```

Only i receive...

```
Notice: Undefined index: check_id in /home/index.php on line 24
```

Printing the array shows my check_id value...

[image]

Comment: Is there a column named `check_id` in `users` table?

Comment: Theres a column yes but its in my actions table @ekad

Comment: `fetchAll()` returns a multidimensional array, so try -> `$checkValue = $row[0]['check_id'];`. Or you could change to `if($row = $query->fetch()){`

Answer (score 2):

You need to;

- Fetch all the results
- Iterate through your result set

```
$arrResults = $query->fetchAll();
foreach($arrResults as $result) {
   echo $result['user_id'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug use print_r

```
if($row = $query->fetchAll()){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the reply @JohanSnowgoose